# Запятая в "так же(,) как и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужно ли в предложении "Питаются бамбуковыми листьями, так же как и их собратья — большие панды" ставить запятую перед "как и"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном предложении знаки препинания расставлены верно.

*Питаются бамбуковыми листьями, **так же как и** их собратья — большие панды.*

[**(ТОЧНО) ТАК ЖЕ КАК (И)**, союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_738)

> То же, что «равно как (и)». Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «(точно) так же как (и)», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. Между частями союза запятая не ставится.
>
> ! Не смешивать с сочетанием местоименного определителя «так» с частицей «же» и союза «как (и)».

Запятая ставилась бы в таком предложении:

*Питаются **так же** [таким же образом]**, как и** их собратья.*